# How to use nunc dimittis?

Tags: parts-of-speech, latin

Just learned this word from my glance at Shakespeare-period poem. I'd like to know what's the property of this word, meaning is it an adjective or a noun? How do I use it in the modern writing?

Comment: What was the "Shakespeare-period poem"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach poems written within that period of time or the period long before modernism emerged.

Comment: Well, you must have encountered it somewhere. Why not say where? Why not include the results of your own research? "Share your research"

Comment: Like I said, I glanced at a poem which I don't know the name, and this word interested me, I googled it, found it has something to do with farewell and first appeared in hymns. Yet I really want to know how to use it in the modern writing, like creative writing or essay etc. Sorry for the inconvenience I've made.

Comment: Ask questions about Latin phrases at [latin.se], not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nunc dimittis*, "Now thou sendest away", is the opening phrase of Simeon's hymn at Luke 29-32 as it appears in the Vulgate, the Latin translation of the Bible:

> 29 Lord, now lettest thou thy servant depart in peace, according to thy word:
>   30 For mine eyes have seen thy salvation,
>   31 Which thou hast prepared before the face of all people;
>   32 A light to lighten the Gentiles, and the glory of thy people Israel.

It's used as the name of that hymn and of musical settings of it. It is also occasionally used figuratively to designate a retirement or resignation, or the successful conclusion of some arduous effort. When Huxley wrote Darwin that he had read *The Origin  of Species* and was completely convinced of the fact of evolution, Darwin responded:

> I had awful misgivings and thought perhaps I had deluded myself, like so many have done ; and I then fixed in my mind three judges, on whose decision I determined mentally to abide. The judges were Lyell, Hooker, and yourself. It was this which made me so excessively anxious for your verdict. I am now contented, and can sing my *Nunc Dimittis*.

To the best of my knowledge, Shakespeare never uses the phrase; it does not appear in the concordances.

Comment: Thanks for correction. I meant some poem from Shakespeare's time.

Comment: The 'Nunc dimittis' is part of the service of Evensong in the Book of Common Prayer, still called by its Latin name even though sung in English. That's the only context in which the phrase would be used in modern writing.